# Why child created with new Vue.extend() does not get rendered in parent

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Why child does not get rendered in parent even though component is created with a component constructor returned with `Vue.extend()`

```
var newChild = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div> {{ childMsg }} </div>',
  data() {
    return {
      childMsg: 'Child World'
    }
  }
})

var child = new newChild()

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  },
  components: {
      child: child
  }
})
```

**template**

```
<div id="app">
  <div>{{msg}}</div>
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extend` method is [to extend an already existing component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend). In this case, what you want is to create a new component. You can do this by using the `component` method, and the first argument, preceding the component properties, is the component name.

Knowing that, you could adapt the code like this:

```
var newChild = Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div> {{ childMsg }} </div>',
  data() {
    return {
      childMsg: 'Child World'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  },
  components: {
      child: newChild
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

don't need use new newChild, just use:

```
 components: {
  child: newChild
 }
```

when use new newChild, should be like this:

```
 new newChild.$mount("#dom")
```